# DSYM uploaded without version UUID

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics, fastlane, dsym

On iOS, I am sending the DSYMs files using the follow fastlane script:

```
fastlane run upload_symbols_to_crashlytics
```

But for some reason the DSYMs are appearing without version in Crashlytics, I tried to send it manually using the command line from Firebase:

```
Pods/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols
```

But I am still having the same problem, what can be the reason for this?